# Notification from Flask to JS using socket.IO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using the Flask-SocketIO library which works fine but I need to send a notification with emit to the outside of a socket.io decorator and it's a real pain. Looking at the solutions, many people use rabbitmq or redis but I don't know how to use them.

Here's my code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flaskwebgui import FlaskUI
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
async_mode = None
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode, message_queue='amqp:///socketio')

def run_sock(): 
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)

ui = FlaskUI(app, fullscreen=True, server=run_sock,)

@app.route("/")
def index():  
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('test', namespace='/test')
def test():
    print("test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ui.run()
    io = SocketIO(message_queue='amqp:///socketio')
    io.emit('test_emit', {'data': 'toto'}, namespace='/test')
```

My JS front-end never gets the test_emit message, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your emit is that it appears below the `ui.run()` call, which does not return until you close the application. Move the emit to any function in your application that executes while the server is running (such as a Flask view function) and it should work just fine.

Why do you have two `SocketIO` objects in the same process? The `socketio` instance that you defined near the top of the script can be used anywhere within the process, no need to create a second instance. You do not need to use a message queue for this problem, since you have all the usages of Socket.IO within a single process.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. The above is a simple example of my application. I need to warn the front in javascript when an action happens on my system (banching a usb key for example). So I can't put the emit before ```ui.run()``` is launched.

Comment: Of course. Putting it before ui.run() would not work either. It needs to be issued while your application is running, not before and not after. As I said, it has to go in a function that executes while your app is actively running, such as a view function.